# showing a large pdf file embedded on a browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to show a pdf file embedded in my browser window. My code shows a small pdf file on the browser, but it does not show the large pdf file. Below is my code:

Model class:

```
public  class FileModel
    {
        public int FileModelId { get; set; }
        public byte[]? FileName { get; set; }
        public string? Url { get; set; }

        public string InlineMarkup
        {
            get
            {
                return String.Format("data:application/pdf;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(this.FileName));
            }
        }
    }
```

My controller class Index method:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine("FilledPDFFiles//Package2022.pdf");
                string filePath2 = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "FilledPDFFiles//Package2022.pdf");
                byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath2);
                FileModel profile = new FileModel
                {
                    Url = filePath,
                    FileName = bytes
                };
                return View(profile);

            }
```

My razor View:

```
@model AckPackage.Models.FileModel


<embed src="@Model.InlineMarkup" width="100% " height="1000px" type="application/pdf">
```

Above code works fine if the pdf file is around 373 KB. I am trying to embed a 2330 KB file on the web browser. Is their any way to display large pdf files. Below is my directory structure

[image]

Hello Md Farid Uddin Kiron,

I tried your solution, but getting this error. The pdf file size is around 3000 KB. Please see the screen shot:

[image]

below are the chrome browser settings:

[image]

error in pdf file. i put a new pdf file and I can open that file, but as soon as I run my code, the file becomes corrupt and cannot be viewed. below is the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Would you kindly have a test on eadge browser if the issue persist. Code snippet shouldn't break unless browser restrict you.

Comment: Would you kindly have a try now , I hope it would work in google chrome as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to embed a 2330 KB file on the web browser. Is their any
> way to display large pdf files.

Well, seems you are having issue on displaying large PDF file on brwser. Obviously, you can. In fact, the way is much cleaner and efficient no matter how large the pdf is. I have checked with up to 10,000 KB size. Here is the implementation below:

**Embed Large PDF:**

Controller:

```
public IActionResult DisplayLargePdf()
        {
           

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {


                string embed = "<object data=\"{0}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"1000px\" height=\"600px\">";
                embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}\">here</a>";
                embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
                embed += "</object>";

                TempData["Embed"] = string.Format(embed, "/YourFolderName/YourFileName.pdf");
                return View();
            }

        }
```

View:

```
@Html.Raw(TempData["Embed"])
```

Output:

[image]

**Browser Seettings:**

If your browser restricts you, in that scenario, you should configure your browser setting. For Edge you can configure as following.

[image]

In addition, if you would like to download in that scenario you could have a try following code snippet:

**Download Large Pdf:**

```
public ActionResult DownloadlargePDF()
        {
            string physicalPath = "wwwroot/YourFolderName/YourPDFFileName.pdf";
            byte[] pdfBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(physicalPath);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);

            string mimeType = "application/pdf";
            return new FileStreamResult(stream, mimeType)
            {
                FileDownloadName = "AnyNameYouWantToSet.pdf"
            };

        }
```

**Update:**

Please get rid of  `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path + "/Cambridge-IELTS-15-General.pdf", stream.ToArray());` and the string path = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "Documents"); line it will resolve your issue. The key part is `<object data` which would display PDF for you. I have tested just google chrome as well and working accordingly.

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution, but keep getting an error saying "Failed to load PDF document. I modified my original question with the screen shots of the error I am getting. I also put the screen shot of chrome browser settings.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Seems, Its certainly the browser issue for sure not the solution, would you kindly have a try in eadge please to narrow down the issue first if the issue persist there. I have actually tested in eadge.

Comment: And please reopene the browser after changing the settings.

Comment: I am getting the same error in edge, I put the new pdf file in the folder and when I run the code. I get the error. I pasted the error above.

Comment: Somehow as soon as I run the code, the file become damaged. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: As you can watch my capture that's fine and each time getting correct file. Would you kindly confirm in which browser it causing?

Comment: I put a new pdf file in my folder and as soon as this line runs the .pdf file becomes corrupted and no readable and throws the error that I pasted above. Both Chrome and edge browser are doing the same thing. It is not the browser. it is this line of code: System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path + "/Package2022.pdf", stream.ToArray()); that is corrupting the file.

Comment: Please have try the updated solution and remove `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes` line and path as well as its not required as per your scenario. Thanks

Comment: Your second solution worked.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was clueless reagarding your issue because I have tested both in eadge, chrome, local, IIS and azure and got expected result. Anyway, thanks for your cooperation.